# C# My second from is gray out when called from the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

Using the main thread:
when my form is displayed all fields are grey out and all updates to the form are grey out as well.

```
StopServicesForm stopservices = new StopServicesForm(
cicsRegionSelected, serverSelected);
stopservices.Show();
stopservices.stopAppServerService();

*On page load*
private void StopServicesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Region_label.Visible = true;
   displayregion_label.Visible = true;
   StoppingServicelabel1.Visible = true;
   ServiceNamelabel.Visible = true;
   Service_progressBar1.Visible = true;
}
```

Using a new thread:
The Join method seems to display the second form as a modal window. All field are displayed however the fields are not updated while the thread is running.

```
StopServicesForm stopservices = new StopServicesForm(
cicsRegionSelected, serverSelected);
stopservices.Sendstopserviceupdate = new
StopservicethreadCompleted(StopServicethreadCompleteCallback);
Thread thread = new Thread(stopservices.stopAppServerService);
stopservices.Show();
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

I'm using the following delegate instances to update the form since I'm using a new thread.

```
SetTextCallback setSet_tbServiceNameText = new SetTextCallback(results.Set_tbServiceName);            
UpdateProgressDelegate updateprog = new UpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateprogressBar);
UpdateServicetoStopLabel updateserviceName = new UpdateServicetoStopLabel(UpdateServicetostopLabel);
```

If I don't use the Join Method, everything works except my main runs still the end; which terminates the app before the new thread is completed. 
I have spent sometime trying to figure this out so any help will be much apprieciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ShowDialog` to show a form as a modal dialog, rather than blocking the UI thread by a `Join` call.